# Newbe Ubuntu installer - Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS 64bit - Windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, usb

Having some issues installing Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS 64bit next to Windows 10.

This is what I did:

1) Created a bootable usb with ubuntu on it using Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.6.3

2) Changed the boot mode

3) Boot from USB
- It showed the option to test drive or install - I chose install

4) Choose Language

5) Setup Wireless - I didn't choose anything here

6) Then it showed me the preparing to install

7) After that a message popped up saying:

> **Unmount partitions that are in use** The installer has detected that the following discs have mounted partitions /dev/scd Do you want the
>   installer to try and unmount these partitions before continuing? If
>   you leave them mounted, you will not be able to create, delete, resize
>   partitions on these discs, but you may be able to install on an
>   existing partition there.

So obviously I said yes.

8) Installation type - I chose something else - This looked nothing like the screen shots I saw on the installation guide.

[installation type window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qK0bP.jpg)

9) Then it only gave me the option to choose my bootable usb for the installation. With a bunch of options to choose, so I got scared and quit.

[Installation type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oex3n.jpg)

Can any one please help?

Keep in my mind I do not know a lot, so please dumb it down.
Why can't I choose to run it along side Windows 10?
Why doesn't the installation pick up my hard drives?

If you need any other info, please ask. But I think I put everything in here.

Comment: First you have to turn off fast boot (and maybe also secure boot) of UEFI in Windows 10. Then shutdown the computer completely and try again

Comment: disabling secure boot works fine with me. Open bios and disable secure boot, and enable load legacy option.

Comment: @dragon2fly I did all of those still no luck. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Just a feeling, select  a try ubuntu option and open a terminal and `[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo UEFI || echo BIOS`. If the result is not `UEFI`, you need to try another way to make that USB.

Comment: I have amazingly just read something similar. Am going to try it now. Thanks

Comment: How and where do I do that? Seemed easier when I wasn't in front of the pc. Sorry.

Comment: I found the "DOS" but the command doesn't seem to be working

Comment: The answer is UEFI

Comment: @dragon2fly Can the problem that it isn't picking up the hard drives? how would one remedy this?

Comment: How many hard drive are you have? Still in the `Try ubuntu` mode, open `Gparted ` and see if gparted can detect your hard drives correctly?

Comment: I have a 32gig SSD and a 500gig HHD. They seem to be merged under the c drive in windows. I will have a look

Comment: "Since GParted is a powerful tool capable of destroying partition tables and vast amounts of data, only root may run it." Their words

Comment: @dragon2fly Are you out of ideas? Because I know I am

Comment: well, ignore their message, `Gparted` should run and see something about your hard drives. And could you try an usb created by this method https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager/iso2usb for both ubuntu 14 and 15.10 ?

Comment: @dragon2fly I did new bootable usb - no luck so far.  As for gpart 'ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ gpart
Usage: gpart [options] device
Options: [-b <backup MBR>][-C c,h,s][-c][-d][-E][-e][-f][-g][-h][-i]
         [-K <last sector>][-k <# of sectors>][-L][-l <log file>]
         [-n <increment>][-q][-s <sector-size>][-t <module-name>]
         [-V][-v][-W <device>][-w <module-name,weight>]
gpart v0.1h (c) 1999-2001 Michail Brzitwa <michail@brzitwa.de>.
Guess PC-type hard disk partitions.' Whats next?

Comment: @dragon2fly [This is where I get stuck](http://imgur.com/1izCaLJ) I have no option to choose any other drive... It feels like I keep repeating myself but hopefully this gpart thing can pan out something useful. This experience has certainly upped my knowledge base quite a bit.

Comment: Here is a Gparted Screen-shot [Gparted](http://imgur.com/HX41mV0) I'm going to try and install Ubuntu again. It asked me fix a bunch of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem of not picking up any drives was a lot easier to solve in the end than I initially thought:

1) Run Ubuntu Install in "Try Ubuntu" mode

2) Connect to Wifi [wifi](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-connect.html)

2) Click on the top Ubuntu icon and search for "Terminal"

3) [Install universe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) - The link will help you do so.

4) Install Gparted by typing the following in terminal:

> sudo apt-get install gparted

5) Gparted should be installed - Click on the top Ubuntu icon and search for "Gparted"

6) Run Gparted - If you couldn't find your internal drives either, Gparted would pick it up and ask if it can fix those problems. Allow him to do so.

You should be ready to install Ubuntu now.

Please feel free to edit this answer, I am still a novice Ubuntu user and might have slipped up on some terminology, or messed up some steps.

@dragon2fly - I couldn't have done it without you. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm glad that you have solved your problem :D .  However, in `Try Ubuntu` mode, I'm confused that mode where can you find `gpart` not `gparted` and why do you have to install `gparted` since it is already there? (I've just comfirmed that with 14.04.3 iso image with my virtualbox)

Comment: @dragon2fly when I typed in the command that you gave me for Gparted, terminal told me that it wasn't installed. So I did. I'm not sure if the missing install was part of the ISO not being correctly written to the bootable USB or not but it wasn't there. I'm glad it got sorted too. It was a 6 day install but it is done.