# My Ubuntu 14.04.03 installation does not pick up my c drive - Windows 10

Tags: hard-drive, 64-bit, windows-10, toshiba-satellite, usb-installation

I am at my wits end, and google wont give me any new answers.

Could you please help.

**My wants and needs**

- Installation does not look like the guide.
- I want to overwrite Windows 10. (Initially along side it)
- I have disabled all the fast and secure etc. boot goodies. That is my technical jargon.
- There is no drive to choose from in the installation process except for my bootable usb, and yes it is UEFI.

**My laptop**

- Toshiba Satellite U840W-F747
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-317U CPU @ 170GHz
- 10 GB RAM
- x64-based proccessor

*So can you guys help?*

**More info:**

[welcome screen](http://blog.sudobits.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/welcome-screen.jpg); 
[installation type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCxpN.png)

Comment: Did you completely shut down Windows? (Not only hibernate) Also, what kind of storage device is Windows installed on? Can you see the drive in GParted, the partition manager that comes in the live system? And in what kind does it differ from the installation guide?

Comment: @the_Seppi I shut down windows completely. I turned off windows hybernation

Comment: @the_Seppi Hitachi Hitachi 500 GIG and then there is a SSD 32 GIG where 11 GIG is used and the other space is free. I am not sure what it is used for.

Comment: @the_Seppi I ran Gparted in try mode of Ubuntu. I got the following message: "Since GParted is a powerful tool capable of destroying partition tables and vast amounts of data, only root may run it."

Comment: @the_Seppi When I am in try Ubuntu mode, When I go into discs, I can see all the discs. When I go into the file manager, I can see the C drive.

Comment: @the_Seppi In the first window(the welcome window), there is no pictures or text, just an option to choose the language, and a quit and install button.

Comment: @the_Seppi And then the wifi screen is the same, and the window that checks that you have external power, space, and wifi.

Comment: @the_Seppi Then I can't choose a drive to install it on.

Comment: what is the main problem?Can you please explain it briefly at once?So that we will be able to help.It's unclear at the moment actually.

Comment: @Rahul Singh There is no drive to choose from in the installation process except for my bootable USB. This is in the step where you are supposed to be able to set a partition table.

Comment: Ok..so you mean to say that you want to dual boot your pc.I am guesssing your windows is all good and when you are going to install ubuntu alongside .Are you talking about  partitioning of hard drive while running windows or when you are installing ubuntu you are talking about the LVM partition?

Comment: @RahulSingh "I want to overwrite Windows 10. (Initially along side it)" That was my initial idea but I don't really care if I scrap windows.(merged the partition with C again) According to what I know, windows is running fine. I am not sure what you mean by LVM, but from what I understand from google, yes. I did it in windows before hand with "AOMEI Partition Assistant Standard Edition 6.0" Please don't get to technical on me. I am not an electronics engineer or any kind of genius techie.

Comment: @RahulSingh Maybe the new link I put in the question section will explain my problem better (installation type)...  there where the table is with device and /dev/sda below, and free space below that... I have nothing there. The drop down menu to choose a disc space... I only have my flash drive there(4 GIG) So my problem is that I can't install Ubuntu because I can not choose a space to install it on. I hope this cleared it up.

Answer (score 0):

Ok bro.So here what i would suggest.

> But after that you won't have windows any longer and only Ubuntu as your only OS.And the process can't be reversed(Please note that).

First of all if Windows is working properly and you want to only keep Ubuntu as your OS then you have to clear your whole hard drive.

> That means delete all the partitions i.e the local drives(E:/, F:/) and others by refering to this site(don't delete the C drive now it's not necessary).
>
> http://www.disk-partition.com/help/clear-disk.html.
>   Also there are other websites on google which you can refer to delete all the partitions completely.

Now in case when you don't have any drives except the C drive and you see that it's not taking the whole capacity of your hard drive then just make sure that all the space is unallocated which will be after you delete the partitions.

> (It will be better if you install Ubuntu 14.04 because right now it's the long term support release).
>    After that when you are installing Ubuntu from your flash drive or cd, you will probably see 5 options.
>
> Now as said previously you won't have your windows partition after this step.The only OS will be Ubuntu.So select the option which says install Ubuntu and erase the disk completely.
>   It will erase everything and after that the steps are easy you will be able to understand them.

So I guess it will clear your doubts.
Don't be nervous.Install Ubuntu for now.After doing the whole process of installing OS once you will be able to understand it and it will be no problem when you do it again.
So try it.

Comment: There are no partitions... [Can't merge partitions](http://imgur.com/GZUfzvq) [My HDD](http://imgur.com/8I1rSVx) You clearly don't understand the problem. In the Ubuntu installation when I need a place to install ubuntu, I have no options to choose from. Say "oh okay" if you understand.

Comment: Sorry, that last part was rude. I am just a bit frustrated with this process at the moment.

Comment: Not a problem buddy.It happens in frustration.Ok then delete all the partitions even the C drive .You will be without an OS now.But it should  then automatically merge the whole hard disk space in one.

Comment: And if it doesn't work, then I can't work, or easily get advice on how to fix it.

Comment: Sorry bro.but to learn something you have to risk something.Otherwise you can take help from your friends.Now it's upto you.But see I too recently got rid of my Windows 8 and installed Ubuntu because it's fun to do so.That's it.

Comment: I hear you but just to wipe a disc because Ubuntu install can't pick it up is idiotic. A man's got to eat and to do so he has to work. Wiping the disc doesn't solve a problem. You are just hoping that it would by pass the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Newbe Ubuntu installer - Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS 64bit - Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/719336/newbe-ubuntu-installer-ubuntu-14-04-3-lts-64bit-windows-10/721130#721130)

This is the solution to the problem. With some help of users, we actively solved the problem.